# backend cache key really need being hashed?

Tags: php, caching, hash

I'm retrieving data from db and save it in cache under a `key = user.id.1`

I saw people using `md5(key)` or `salt . md5(key)` and advising to don't use stronger encryptions methods to don't add overhead.

If someone wants to access your cached data needs access to server, md5 is easily cracked these days, a salt seems to be pointless in this case and hashing the key will still not help with key collision if is the same key.

What's the reason to use a hash for the key?

Thanks

Comment: I'll add some oil to the fire you started - why use cache in this scenario? What's the reason behind it? It's more than likely that using the cache slows everything down rather than help speed it up.

Comment: that's just as example for a key and not the point of my question

Comment: So ask the guy whose software you were looking at and ask him/her why they chose a hash for caching key. It's much easier to do that than starting an opinionated discussion.

Comment: are you trying to be a troll or missing the point of stackoverflow?
I did some research and couldn't find an aswer to this question, so I'm asking here. If you have the knowledge, you are free to share it.

Comment: You didn't present a **programming** problem. You are missing the point of SO. Ask the person whose system you used. One use of a hashed key is to have equal length keys and to avoid potential key naming issues (special characters are avoided and what not). And also, a collision even with md5 is not that likely to happen. It's also a fast algorithm and cache isn't considered as critical data so an algorithm such as md5 can be used with it, it's quick, easy and it works for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no need to do that for short keys. Hashing would be good if you're going to cache for example a long select query. It'll be better to keep 32 chars instead of long 200 chars. If you use hash for short key, you will have 32 chars instead of 7 or 10 chars.